# Ract styled-components slow

Tags: styled-components

Is it really that slow? Should it be so, or something's wrong with my implementation?

P.S. 2 input fields form with one button.

Without styled-components: (523ms Scripting)

[image: without styled-components load] im[1]]

With styled-components: (3161ms Scripting)
[image: styled-components load]

Comment: Yeah react styled-components is that slow, it's ridiculous, practically worthless to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Styled Components is slow because it's a CSS-in-JS solution. This means your page must go through these steps:

1. page is loaded;
2. JavaScript code is parsed;
3. CSS is generated;
4. CSS is injected into components;
5. browser renders the CSS.

When you have plain CSS files (like when you use CSS modules), the steps are:

1. page is loaded;
2. JavaScript code is parsed; browser renders CSS in parallel.

Styled Components gives you the powerful ability to inject code dinamically into the CSS, but there is no free lunch: and the cost here is performance. In the long run, the best solution to me seems to be SCSS modules (that is, CSS modules combined with SCSS).

Then, if you need to inject code into the CSS, simply set CSS `--variables` dinamically.